# UIActivityViewController freezes when email or text but not fb or Twitter

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a very standard implementation of UIActivityViewController.  When I use Twitter or Facebook, the view controller is dismissed, and the app continues working.  However, when I email or text the same content, the view controller is dismissed but the app freezes (not crashes).  Everything is still on screen but frozen - no input etc.

Perhaps the Mail or Message apps have not released control back to my app?  Is there a way using Instruments to analyze what's going on?

Thanks!

I am getting a leak from this part from NSArray as the offenders

```
- (void)postToFacebook:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSString *postText = @"Testing";
    UIImage *imageToPost = [self captureTheScreenImage];
    NSArray *postItems = @[postText, imageToPost];

    UIActivityViewController *activityPostVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:postItems applicationActivities:nil];


    NSArray *excludedItems = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    [activityPostVC setExcludedActivityTypes:excludedItems];

    [self presentViewController:activityPostVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: are you by any chance presenting the UIActivityViewController from a secondary UIWindow? I had a similar issue under this conditions and found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, like you mentioned, using Instruments.  But If I were to foreshadow your results, I'd say you might want to do network calls on a non-UI thread, somewhere in the background so that your UI thread can do its thang while your app talks to Twitter or Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me too when using multiple `UIWindow` objects at the same time.

Upon dismissal of the `UIActivityViewController`, the presenting windows contents are not restored correctly. Specifically, the window's first subview (`UILayoutContainerView`) is missing its constraints to the superview. This causes the window the width of the `UILayoutContainerView` to be zero causing the window appear transparent and reveal the window underneath it but not allowing user interaction.

The fix can be to place an empty transparent window on top of the current window and present the `UIActivityViewController` from an empty view controller associated with that new window. When the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed, we can dispose of the empty window that it was presented from.

```
import Foundation

private var previousWindow: UIWindow?
private var activityViewControllerWindow: UIWindow?

extension UIViewController {

  fileprivate var isActivityViewControllerWindowPresented: Bool {
    return activityViewControllerWindow?.isKeyWindow ?? false
  }

  func presentActivityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if isActivityViewControllerWindowPresented {
      return
    }

    let window = UIWindow(frame: view.window!.frame)
    previousWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    activityViewControllerWindow = window
    window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let activityCompletionClosure = activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] (activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError) in
      self?.cleanUpActivityViewControllerWindow()
      activityCompletionClosure?(activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError)
    }

    window.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: animated, completion: completion)
  }

  fileprivate func cleanUpActivityViewControllerWindow() {
    previousWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    activityViewControllerWindow?.rootViewController = nil
    activityViewControllerWindow = nil
  }

}
```

Comment: Amazing!!! I had a global overlay of an alert on the keyWindow / lastWindow, could not figure out how to dismiss it as it always left a UIRemoteKeyboardWindow, or TransitioningView behind that would stay there in the background inaccessible, thus I could not overall the device window for the alert!! Thank you soooooo Much!!